What are good test cases for benchmarking and scaling studies of SIESTA on up to a few thousand cores?
Subject says it all.  I'm looking for SIESTA test cases suitable for benchmarking and scaling studies on clusters having up to a few thousand cores.

+1. Welcome to our community.
